# How to Change System Date of a Remote System Programatically

Tags: c#, datetime, ip-address

While in research I seen a post

[Change system date programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650849/how-to-change-system-date-programatically)

This is how to change the DateTime of local system.
I want to change date of a `Remote system`, by giving the `IP Address` or `Computer Name`.

Any help would be appreciated .

Thanks

Comment: That question does have an answer discussing using WMI, and you can [use WMI remotely](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2007/11/16/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-set-the-date-and-time-on-a-computer.aspx), I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [psexec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553) to execute your code remotely.