# Strategy to change system time via WPF client application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I found good advice how to change system time [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650849/how-to-change-system-date-programatically).

It's ok... But what is the best strategy to change system local time for the WPF client application then?

For example my application periodically gets some data from server and I can pass the server time with it.

Or may be is better to use additional `thread` to ask server about the server time and change local  system time always...

So I don't know which approach is better...

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: How often do you need to keep your client up to date?

Comment: @AnuragRanjhan Well in fact client gets some data periodically every 3 minutes. So it should be in time all things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better not to do it at all - it requires admin privileges to change system time, so your program will have to run as admin (may be acceptable in your case, but normally not a good idea).

It is also requires some effort to correctly adjust for network latency when setting time. Please check out how it is normally done, i.e. starting with [NTP - Network Time Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol).

One option is to configure windows to check time more often itself instead doing it by hand as it already implements the functionality.

Comment: You can check out [this NTP Snippet](http://dotnet-snippets.com/dns/c-simple-network-time-ntp-protocol-client-SID571.aspx) if you want to go this route