# Is there a way to open Windows date and time settings dialog from a WinForms application?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, winapi, datetime

I'm working on an embedded software, where we would like to avoid exposing Windows features and interfaces as much as possible. However, users need the ability to change the system date and time, and perhaps also timezone or daylight saving mode.

I thought I would create our own simple Form for that and I tried digging into Win32 API calls, but realized that it's not a simple way.

So I found that basically the easiest way here would be to invoke the well-known Windows dialog from the software and let users changing stuff there. I couldn't find anything about it so far. Is there any executable for it (such as gpedit.msc for example), or is there any API calls to show that window? If not, or in case of any contras which I didn't take into count, can anyone suggest a better way for this task?

EDIT: Thank you for the timedate.cpl tip, I will try it as soon as I can.

Comment: You know you need admin rights to change the time? Will that be a problem?

Comment: Admin rights are not problem because of being on embedded platform, we have only one user with admin rights.

Comment: You may want to take a look to this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650849/change-system-date-programatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my desktop version of Windows you can show that dialog by executing `timedate.cpl`. I've no idea whether or not that will work on your embedded Windows.

Comment: It is working in our embedded environment as well, however, I have no idea on which package it depends on. But for now it doesn't matter. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is. Use this code and upon button clicking it will work:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("timedate.cpl");
```

It should work. If you want to open other windows controls you only have to change `"timedata.cpl"` to the command of your choice.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Process.Start(System.Environment.SystemDirectory + @"\TimeDate.cpl");
```

But I don't know if it works on your embedded Windows...