# setting system time based on the calculated datetime in c#

Tags: c#, linq, systemtime

i have copied the code , i have a variable ("Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime") i want to change system time with the datetime available in (Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime) whenever

```
if (compare == 0 || compare > 0)
{
    Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime = Max.AddMinutes(5);

    Console.WriteLine("----------");
    Console.WriteLine("modifiedtime");
    Console.WriteLine(Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime);
    Console.WriteLine("----------");

}
```

Loop is executed.

Thanks in adavnce.

```
using System;
using System.Management;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;


namespace datetime_1
{
    public class RemoteConnect
    {

        public class Modifiedtime_1
        {
            public static DateTime? Modifiedtime = null;
        }


        public static void Main()
        {

            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine("\a");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.Clear();

                ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
                options.EnablePrivileges = true;
                options.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
                options.Authority = "ntlmdomain:node1.local";
                options.Username = "user1";
                options.Password = "xxxxxx";

                ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\node1\root\cimv2"), options);
                scope.Connect();

                if (scope.IsConnected == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("node1 Connection Succeeded");

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("node1 Connection Failed");
                }

                ConnectionOptions options1 = new ConnectionOptions();
                options1.EnablePrivileges = true;
                options1.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                options1.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
                options1.Authority = "ntlmdomain:node2.local";
                options1.Username = "user2";
                options1.Password = "xxxxxx";


                ManagementScope scope1 = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\node2\root\cimv2"), options1);
                scope1.Connect();

                if (scope1.IsConnected == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("node2 Connection Succeeded");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("node2 Connection Failed");
                }

                ConnectionOptions options3 = new ConnectionOptions();

                options3.EnablePrivileges = true;
                options3.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                options3.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
                options3.Authority = "ntlmdomain:WORKGROUP";
                options3.Username = "user2";
                options3.Password = "xxxx";

                ManagementScope scope3 = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\node3\root\cimv2"), options3);
                scope3.Connect();

                if (scope3.IsConnected == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("node3 Connection Succeeded");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("node3 Connection Failed");
                }

                ConnectionOptions options4 = new ConnectionOptions();
                options4.EnablePrivileges = true;
                options4.Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                options4.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
                options4.Authority = "ntlmdomain:Workgroup";
                options4.Username = "user4";
                options4.Password = "xxxxxx";

                ManagementScope scope4 = new ManagementScope(string.Format(@"\\node4\root\cimv2"), options4);
                scope4.Connect();

                if (scope4.IsConnected == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("node4 Connection Succeeded");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("node4 Connection Failed");

                }

                DateTime Localdatetime = DateTime.Now;

                ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LocalTime");

                ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

                foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                    Console.WriteLine("node1");
                    Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

                    Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}-{1}-{2}", queryObj["Year"], queryObj["Month"], queryObj["Day"]);
                    Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}:{1}:{2}", queryObj["Hour"], queryObj["Minute"], queryObj["Second"]);
                    String node1_Hour_TEMP = queryObj["Hour"].ToString();
                    String node1_Minute_TEMP = queryObj["Minute"].ToString();
                    String node1_SECOND_TEMP = queryObj["Second"].ToString();
                    String node1_Year_TEMP = queryObj["Year"].ToString();
                    String node1_Month_TEMP = queryObj["Month"].ToString();
                    String node1_Day_TEMP = queryObj["Day"].ToString();

                    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher1 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope1, query);

                    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj1 in searcher1.Get())
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                        Console.WriteLine("node2");
                        Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

                        Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}-{1}-{2}", queryObj1["Year"], queryObj1["Month"], queryObj1["Day"]);
                        Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}:{1}:{2}", queryObj1["Hour"], queryObj1["Minute"], queryObj1["Second"]);
                        String node2_Hour_TEMP = queryObj1["Hour"].ToString();
                        String node2_Minute_TEMP = queryObj1["Minute"].ToString();
                        String node2_SECOND_TEMP = queryObj1["Second"].ToString();
                        String node2_Year_TEMP = queryObj1["Year"].ToString();
                        String node2_Month_TEMP = queryObj1["Month"].ToString();
                        String node2_Day_TEMP = queryObj1["Day"].ToString();

                        ManagementObjectSearcher searcher2 =
                            new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope3, query);

                        foreach (ManagementObject queryObj2 in searcher2.Get())
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                            Console.WriteLine("node3");
                            Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

                            Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}-{1}-{2}", queryObj2["Year"], queryObj2["Month"], queryObj2["Day"]);
                            Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}:{1}:{2}", queryObj2["Hour"], queryObj2["Minute"], queryObj2["Second"]);
                            String node3_Hour_TEMP = queryObj2["Hour"].ToString();
                            String node3_Minute_TEMP = queryObj2["Minute"].ToString();
                            String node3_SECOND_TEMP = queryObj2["Second"].ToString();
                            String node3_Year_TEMP = queryObj2["Year"].ToString();
                            String node3_Month_TEMP = queryObj2["Month"].ToString();
                            String node3_Day_TEMP = queryObj2["Day"].ToString();


                            ObjectQuery query4 = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_LocalTime");

                            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher4 = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope4, query);

                            foreach (ManagementObject queryObj4 in searcher4.Get())
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");
                                Console.WriteLine("node4");
                                Console.WriteLine("-----------------------------------");

                                Console.WriteLine("Date: {0}-{1}-{2}", queryObj4["Year"], queryObj4["Month"], queryObj4["Day"]);
                                Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}:{1}:{2}", queryObj4["Hour"], queryObj4["Minute"], queryObj4["Second"]);
                                String node4_Hour_TEMP = queryObj4["Hour"].ToString();
                                String node4_Minute_TEMP = queryObj4["Minute"].ToString();
                                String node4_SECOND_TEMP = queryObj4["Second"].ToString();
                                String node4_Year_TEMP = queryObj4["Year"].ToString();
                                String node4_Month_TEMP = queryObj4["Month"].ToString();
                                String node4_Day_TEMP = queryObj4["Day"].ToString();

                                //Convert DATE Time String to INT
                                int node1_Hour;
                                int.TryParse(node1_Hour_TEMP, out node1_Hour);
                                int node1_Minute;
                                int.TryParse(node1_Minute_TEMP, out node1_Minute);
                                int node1_SECOND;
                                int.TryParse(node1_SECOND_TEMP, out node1_SECOND);
                                int node1_YEAR;
                                int.TryParse(node1_Year_TEMP, out node1_YEAR);
                                int node1_MONTH;
                                int.TryParse(node1_Month_TEMP, out node1_MONTH);
                                int node1_DAY;
                                int.TryParse(node1_Day_TEMP, out node1_DAY);
                                DateTime node1_DATE = new DateTime(node1_YEAR, node1_MONTH, node1_DAY, node1_Hour, node1_Minute, node1_SECOND);

                                //Convert DATE Time String to INT

                                int node2_Hour;
                                int.TryParse(node2_Hour_TEMP, out node2_Hour);
                                int node2_Minute;
                                int.TryParse(node2_Minute_TEMP, out node2_Minute);
                                int node2_SECOND;
                                int.TryParse(node2_SECOND_TEMP, out node2_SECOND);
                                int node2_YEAR;
                                int.TryParse(node2_Year_TEMP, out node2_YEAR);
                                int node2_MONTH;
                                int.TryParse(node2_Month_TEMP, out node2_MONTH);
                                int node2_DAY;
                                int.TryParse(node2_Day_TEMP, out node2_DAY);
                                DateTime node2_DATE = new DateTime(node2_YEAR, node2_MONTH, node2_DAY, node2_Hour, node2_Minute, node2_SECOND);

                                //Convert DATE Time String to INT

                                int node3_Hour;
                                int.TryParse(node3_Hour_TEMP, out node3_Hour);
                                int node3_Minute;
                                int.TryParse(node3_Minute_TEMP, out node3_Minute);
                                int node3_SECOND;
                                int.TryParse(node3_SECOND_TEMP, out node3_SECOND);
                                int node3_YEAR;
                                int.TryParse(node3_Year_TEMP, out node3_YEAR);
                                int node3_MONTH;
                                int.TryParse(node3_Month_TEMP, out node3_MONTH);
                                int node3_DAY;
                                int.TryParse(node3_Day_TEMP, out node3_DAY);
                                DateTime node3_DATE = new DateTime(node3_YEAR, node3_MONTH, node3_DAY, node3_Hour, node3_Minute, node3_SECOND);

                                //Convert DATE Time String to INT

                                int node4_Hour;
                                int.TryParse(node4_Hour_TEMP, out node4_Hour);
                                int node4_Minute;
                                int.TryParse(node4_Minute_TEMP, out node4_Minute);
                                int node4_SECOND;
                                int.TryParse(node4_SECOND_TEMP, out node4_SECOND);
                                int node4_YEAR;
                                int.TryParse(node4_Year_TEMP, out node4_YEAR);
                                int node4_MONTH;
                                int.TryParse(node4_Month_TEMP, out node4_MONTH);
                                int node4_DAY;
                                int.TryParse(node4_Day_TEMP, out node4_DAY);
                                DateTime node4_DATE = new DateTime(node4_YEAR, node4_MONTH, node4_DAY, node4_Hour, node4_Minute, node4_SECOND);
                                Console.WriteLine("LocalDateTime");
                                Console.WriteLine(Localdatetime);

                                Console.WriteLine("=====LINQ=====");
                                var Max = new[] { node1_DATE, node2_DATE, node3_DATE, node4_DATE }.Max();
                                Console.WriteLine(Max);
                                Console.WriteLine("=====LINQEND=====");



                                //compare datetime with local.
                                int compare = DateTime.Compare(Max, Localdatetime);
                                if (compare == 0 || compare > 0)
                                {

                                    Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime = Max.AddMinutes(5);

                                    Console.WriteLine("----------");
                                    Console.WriteLine("modifiedtime");
                                    Console.WriteLine(Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime);
                                    Console.WriteLine("----------");

                                }

                                else
                                {
                                    Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime = Localdatetime;

                                    Console.WriteLine("----------");
                                    Console.WriteLine("modifiedtime");
                                    Console.WriteLine(Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime);
                                    Console.WriteLine("----------");

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: So... what's the problem?

Comment: i dnt know how to change the system time by using c#. i have got the calculated time in a variable and i want to change the system time based on the time availble in the variable.

Comment: You can find an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650849/change-system-date-programatically

Comment: i already came across this code but my problem is i am not able execute the system time change related code due to my code is running in infinite loop. is it possible to merge this code inside

Comment: i already came across the above mentioned link but my problem is i m not able to execute that code since my code is running inside infinite loop. is it possible to merge the code inside the below mentioned loop.

Comment: if (compare == 0 || compare > 0)
{
 Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime = Max.AddMinutes(5);
Console.WriteLine("----------");
Console.WriteLine("modifiedtime");
Console.WriteLine(Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime);
Console.WriteLine("----------");
}
else

Comment: Please edit your code snippet to something more meaningful - there if far too much there to figure out how to help

Comment: pl refer orignal question there i have mentioned the code snippet.

Comment: your original question has *too much* code... What is your specific question, and what specific section of code are you having trouble with?

Comment: My question is i have calculated datetime which i want to use that as system date time. in short i want to modify system date time based on calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do something like this

Before your infinite loop.

```
bool firstPass = true;
```

Inside your loop

```
... Work out what Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime value is.
```

and at the end of the loop

```
if ( firstPass || (..times deviated to much calculation)) 
{
    firstPass = false;

    SetLocalMachineTimeMethod(Modifiedtime_1.Modifiedtime);
}
```

where SetLocalMachineTimeMethod is some routine you call to set the time locally. There is also a possibility of the added refinement of checking the modified time and (local system time) to see if they have drifted apart by too much and then allow the call be be made again.