# How change system time from windows service?

Tags: c#, .net

My server is Windows server 2008 R2. I have some logic need to **detect the time from other place, If the system time not match. I need to change it** . But I don't find the way.

I try also add a console project, every time open it to change the time, But It will **easy to delete** and I heard [Windows server can't start process after Vista](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5308011/1900498).

So Is there a good way to change system time in windows service?

Comment: Below link may have answer how to change system time using setsystemtime 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172517(v=vs.90).aspx
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650849/change-system-date-programatically

Comment: But make sure your service account has privileges to change date time in Windows (Local Service, Local System should be ok).

Comment: There's already a protocol designed to synchronize time across machines (NTP) and windows implements a client for it. Why are you re-inventing the wheel?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Because it can be disable manually.