# Changing system time dynamically win7

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub change_the_time(ByVal NewDateTime As DateTime)
        '
        Dim NewDateTime2 As DateTime
        '
        NewDateTime2 = #5/1/2016 5:52:15 PM#    ' try setting the time to this
        '
        'set the system date and time to this date and time - throw an exception if it can't
        Try
            TimeOfDay = NewDateTime2
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Could not set time. " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Stop)
        End Try
End Sub
```

Hi.
New to the site so hopefully I follow the rules :-)
My questions is how do I successfully change the system time? The above code I found on this site (as well as much info on other parts of my project - thank you!) and there are no errors, but it always throws an exception. I run as admin and I've tried changing the UAC and I still can't change the time. I read that I need to have the SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege set, but I have this set so that all users (ie me) have the right, still nothing. The MS reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717802(v=vs.85).aspx) does not provide much insight.  I suspect it's an issue with privileges, but i can't seem to see how to set what i need. What do I need to do to allow my application to change the system time to a value?

More info...there is another question along the same lines, but it's c# not Vb and I've tried something similar to that code, which is below.  Still

```
Private Sub change_the_time2(ByRef NewDateTime As DateTime)
  Dim d As DateTime
  d = #6/10/2011#   ' try setting the date to this before using NewDateTime
  Dim worked As Boolean
  '
  Try
      worked = setlocaltime(d)
      MsgBox(" 1. Did it work " & worked)
  Catch ex As Exception
      MsgBox(" 2. Did it work " & worked)
  End Try
End Sub

<DllImport("kernel32.dll", setLastError:=True)> _
Private Shared Function setlocaltime(ByRef time As System.DateTime) As Boolean

End Function
```

Comment: What is the exception ?

Comment: Hello SuperPeanut, "Could not set time. Insufficient security permissions to set the system time"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change system date programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650849/change-system-date-programmatically)

Comment: Shouldn't you have the need to run as administrator?

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650849/change-system-date-programmatically) as has been mentioned in the comments. But to clarify for VB.NET as oposed to C#, per one of the answers in that question:

> On Windows Vista, 7, 8 OS this will require a UAC Prompt in order to
> obtain the necessary administrative rights to successfully execute the
> SetSystemTime function.
>
> The reason is that calling process needs the
> SE_SYSTEMTIME_NAME privilege. The SetSystemTime function is expecting
> a SYSTEMTIME struct in coordinated universal time (UTC). It will not
> work as desired otherwise.
>
> Depending on where/ how you are getting
> your DateTime values, it might be best to play it safe and use
> ToUniversalTime() before setting the corresponding values in the
> SYSTEMTIME struct.

Code example (modified for VB.NET):

```
Dim tempDateTime As DateTime = GetDateTimeFromSomeService()
Dim dateTime As DateTime = tempDateTime.ToUniversalTime()

Dim st As SYSTEMTIME
'All of these must be short
st.wYear = dateTime.Year.ToInt16()
st.wMonth = dateTime.Month.ToInt16()
st.wDay = dateTime.Day.ToInt16()
st.wHour = dateTime.Hour.ToInt16()
st.wMinute = dateTime.Minute.ToInt16()
st.wSecond = dateTime.Second.ToInt16()

// invoke the SetSystemTime method now
SetSystemTime(ByRef st)
```

Yes, you need Administrator privileges.

Comment: Thank you! The error wasn't with the code, although thank you for the code above as it is more precise than anything I had.  The code I had worked when run as admin.  I thought I *was* running the code as admin, but a *proper* check showed me otherwise. Thank you again.