# How can I change system date between config date from table in DB and current date?

Tags: c#, date, datetime

I want to switch system date between config date from table in DB and current date.

This is my step.

1. I store configuration datetime to table in database
2. I have add appsetting "UseCurrentDate" with value "True" or "False" in web.config
3. In application start I read appsetting value from web.config and try to switch between 2 system date
4. I try to change date with my config from database with this solution. ([Change system date programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650849/change-system-date-programmatically))
5. How can I switch to current date if I set appsetting value to change system date to current date?
6. Is it a good solution to do this?

Comment: 6: No, it is **never** a good solution changing the system date, instead adjust the software to use a particular date as a parameter instead of using the system date. The rest of your questions are moot, you shouldn't do it.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen is right either pass the date in or hide it behind some interface (`IDateTimeProvider`) and return whichever dates you like in different cases.

Comment: ok I will not do this solution. thank you.