# Change Pocket PC time & date c#

Tags: c#, windows-ce, pocketpc

I am writing an application with C# for Windows CE in Pocket PC and i need to change Pocket PC time & date manually. Is there any solution to change the time and date manually with c# code?
Any ideas please?

Comment: I'm not even sure this is not a joke, but if it isn't, you should show what you have tried and what specific problem you are having. Was .NET even a thing back then?

Comment: I need to sync current time and date with GPRS. My pocket PC device doesn't have sync clock so i have to write a class for it.But i couldn't find any solution and I wanna change the pocket PC date and time for setting in Meter manually.Is it possible?@Crowcoder

Comment: I"m sorry, I don't know. I wasn't even really programming yet when I owned a pocket pc. I'm really curious, how is it you still have an operating Pocket PC in 2020?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Can you try with P/Invoke SetSystemTime from kernel32.dll?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650849/change-system-date-programmatically)

[Windows CE 1.0 and above seems to support that](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/aa450867(v%3dmsdn.10))

> This function sets the current system time and date. The system time
>   is expressed in UTC.
>
> Requirements OS Versions: Windows CE 1.0 and later. Header: Winbase.h.
>   Link Library: Coredll.lib.